# Creating Excel sheets in same workbook in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Need a suggestion in my code.

I have a data frame in sheet1 of workbook:

```
column 1           column 2
000A0000              2
000B0000              3
000A0001              5
000B0001              1
```

My desired result:

in sheet 2 of Workbook:

```
column 1           column 2
 000A0000              2
 000A0001              5
```

In sheet 3 of Workbook:

```
column 1           column 2
 000B0000              3
 000B0001              1
```

I have done my coding:

```
import pandas as pd
file="workbook.xlxs"
print(data.sheet_names)
data=data.parse("sheet1")

substrings = ['A', 'B']

T = {x: df[df['sheet1'].str.contains(x, na=False, regex=False)] for x in substrings]

for key, var in T.items():
    var.to_excel(f'{key}.xlsx', index=False)
```

by this I can create new workbook. But I need to create new worksheet in same workbook.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you want to write into the 3 worksheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add sheets to the same excel file use [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

#reading the sheet1 using read_excel
df = pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

#creating pandas ExcelWriter object and loading the excel file using `openpyxl`    
df_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('workbook.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
excel = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
df_writer.book = excel

#checking string in column 1 and writing those to respective sheets in same workbook
for string in ['A','B']:
    df[df['column 1'].str.contains(string)].to_excel(df_writer,sheet_name=string)
#saving and closing writer
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: @user10309160 You are Welcome!

Comment: hey, A small question. `for string in ['A','B']`  this selects the data which is in the list. What if I want the data which does not contain these list ? help please.

Comment: @user10309160 For example if don't want data in the above list use `df[~df['column 1'].str.contains('A|B')]` which gives rows where both `A` and `B` are not present.

Comment: @user10309160 It does not give the data which have either `A` or `B`. It will not include the data which contains them.

Answer (score 1):

to_excel would not append sheets to your existing file:

use openpyxl instead:(something like below)

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('path+filename_you_want_to_write_in.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('path+filename_you_want_to_write_in.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet_name_as_per_your_choice",index=False)

writer.save()
```

Also if you dynamically want to read through the sheets and not specific sheets:

```
f = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sheet_names = df.sheet_names
for i in list(sheet_names):
    df = pd.read_excel(f,i)
```

This iterates through all your sheets and provides a dataframe based on the sheets.

Comment: Sorry.not helping. As I want to extract the data from Sheet1 , the above code is not helping me

Comment: This isn't the exact code, since I wasn;t clear with your requirement I gave you a reference where you can implement your code :)

Comment: @user10309160 : you will have to read the sheets via whatever method you want. Compute your requirements and then save it via the codes in the answer

Comment: @user10309160 : you can implement the addition code to dynamically read through all your worksheets and create a df.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the xlsxwriter engine.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('<< file_name >>', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')

writer.save()
```