# Append new sheet with data in existing excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reading files (1234-P2P.xlsx, 1234-T2T)  and creating excel file with name 1234.xlsx and sheets inside the file like 'P2P', 'T2T' and so on .
First file read and write is done,When writing 2nd file it overrides first sheet.Need to append new sheet in same file keeping previous sheets.

```
def Userwise(d,filedata):
 splitWord=[]
 splitWord=d.split('-')

 df1=filedata.parse('sheet1')

 writer=ExcelWriter(splitWord[0]+'.xlsx')
 df1.to_excel(writer,splitWord[1],header=True,index=False)
 print(df1)
 writer.save()


path = 'C:\\DE\\pythonFile\\pandas\\Userwise'
d=[]

for f in os.listdir(path):
 filedata=pd.ExcelFile('C:\\DE\\pythonFile\\pandas\\Userwise\\'+f)
 d=f[:-5]
 Userwise(d,filedata)
```

1 file with name '1234.xlsx' with sheets inside like 'P2P', 'T2T' with data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Excel sheets in same workbook in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197807/creating-excel-sheets-in-same-workbook-in-python)